# "ORA-24777: Use of non-migratable database link not allowed" when calling Oracle stored procedure from Windows Service

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, odp.net

I am creating a Windows Service that will regularly call a set of stored procedures on an Oracle Database. These stored procedures all work when called directly using SQL Developer. In addition, these stored procedures all work when called via a console application. However, when calling these stored procedures with a Windows Service, any stored procedure that has a database link (to an SQL Server) in fails.

To isolate the issue, I have done the following...

- Console App and Windows Service use same Oracle Managed Data Reference/Version
- Console App and Windows Service use same exact connection string and app.config settings
- Console App and Windows Service use same exact class for executing the stored procedure
- Simplified the stored procedure with the database link to the following:

  ```
  create or replace 
  PROCEDURE DATALINKTEST AS 
  BEGIN

      DECLARE lv_latest_FileLoadId INT;

      BEGIN
          SELECT MAX(c."FileLoadId")
          INTO lv_latest_FileLoadId
          FROM table@databaselink c
          WHERE c."account_code" = 'account123';
      END;

  END DATALINKTEST;
  ```

Even the above stored procedure generates a "ORA-24777: Use of non-migratable database link not allowed" when called from a Windows Service. However when called from a console app or directly via SQL Developer, it works fine.

I have a feeling the issue lies somewhere with the type of session Oracle is making for the Windows Service. When I did a select on v$session table, I noticed that the Service sessions had a null SQL_ADDRESS and SQL_ID whereas the Console App and SQL Developer had a SQL_ADDRESS and SQL_ID

Thanks in advance,
Gabe B

Comment: Some quick googling suggests you may be able to work around this by 1) making sure the DB link you are using is Public and Shared 2) Set up Oracle to use multi-threaded server, a.k.a. shared server

Comment: Hi @ChristianShay thanks for responding. This is the error I get when I do either of those suggestions...

Error:ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
Cannot begin transaction on HS dblink with migratable transaction enabled

And I can't seem to find anything on google about this error

Comment: I'm out in the weeds here as I know little about DBlinks, but maybe you can do the following to try to get more insight: 1) Try the very latest ODP.NET Managed Driver from nuget.org and 2) Isolate this SP call so it is not part of any other transaction that is going on.

Comment: It looks a potentially related issue was fixed in the latest ODP.NET on nuget so i would definitely try that. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:39:105977131496942::NO::P39_ID:27121

Comment: That fixed it! :D :D Thank you

It looks like Oracle forces multiple connections to the same database to become distributed transactions, and distributed transactions can’t use hetereogenous database links for whatever reason it seems. I changed my program to use a single connection for all of its queries, and it works

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue that is supposed to be fixed in the lastest nuget ODP.NET driver. FYI - you can use 12.1/12.2 ODP.NET against a version 11 database.