# Statement executes but cannot be inserted to a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I have an Oracle linked server `A_STG` to my SQL Server instance, I usually use `openquery` approach to get data from this linked server.

But in this case my `openquery` character limit exceeds 8000. Hence, I'm using the approach below.

Stated below is a simplified query, my actual query exceeds 8000 characters.

```
declare @query as varchar(max)
@query = 'Select po, po_item from table'

create table #A (po int, po_item int)

Insert into #A
    Execute (@query) AT [A_STG]
```

I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "A_STG" returned message
> ORA-24777: use of non-migratable database link not allowed
>
> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "A_STG" returned message
> ORA-24777: use of non-migratable database link not allowed
>
> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 154
> Could not execute statement on remote server 'A_STG'.

But when I take out the insert statement and leave out only execute statement, it returns the output.

Please help!

Comment: This sound similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216283/ora-24777-use-of-non-migratable-database-link-not-allowed-when-calling-oracle

Comment: You can't just stick some dynamic sql in the middle of an insert statement like that. Not sure why you need dynamic here at all. You should be able to just select your data from the linked server. `select po, po_item from [linkserver].[database].[schema].[object]`

Comment: I am using a dynamic statement because the character limit exceeds when using openquery. This approach works with another linked server in the sql server instance. I've checked and both linked server connectiona are public and shared.

Comment: I tried this approach of select po, po_item from [linkserver].[database].[schema].[object]

Comment: It gives an error of "four part name was applied, buy the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use  a catalog or schema"

Comment: For anyone going through the same, I reached a resolution for this using functions. Broke my query to 2 and created 2 functions and and executed the function with an insert statement to a global temp table